# Data types representing native signed and unsigned integer sizes?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, embedded

Is there an integer data type that will always be exactly 2 bytes on 16-bit platforms, 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms, and 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms? Assume C++11, and that it would be used for calculations, not memory addressing.

There's std::size_t, but what's the signed equivalent (std::ptrdiff_t?), and is it guaranteed to fulfill the requirement?

There's std::intptr_t and std::uintptr_t, but [they won't always be the same size as size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t).

There's std::int_leastN_t and std::int_fastN_t, but is either guaranteed to fulfill the requirement, and if so, what is the proper value of 'N'?

Does Boost provide anything like a(n) int_native_t and uint_native_t?

Comment: Isn't that simply `int`?

Comment: that is platform dependent. c++ doesn't tell there is such type you need

Comment: If it's used for calculations, shouldn't the application define the size of integers, rather than the underlying machines?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694131).

Comment: The more intriguing question is, why would you need such a thing?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel and Daniel. Maybe I should just use a std::(u)int_fastN_t sized according to my requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the question is that it's not at all clear how a term such as "16-bit" or "32-bit", which typically arises from what is essentially a CPU implementation detail, translates to user space.

For example, Z80-based 8-bit machines had both 8-bit and 16-bit registers and addressed memory with 16 bits, so their C implementations made `int` 16 bits wide. 16-bit machines (Amiga, Atari ST) had 32-bit registers or used segments to address more than 64k of memory (80286). Amiga C compilers from different manufacturers implemented different width of `int`, and there was no accepted "native" `int`.

The point is not that you can't rely on `int` or `long` to tell you the "size" of an architecture - that is the premise of your question - but that the architecture width is in fact irrelevant for a C implementation. When writing C code, you shouldn't care about the width of your bus, or the number of bits the processor internally grabs at once. (If you really need to care about that, you're likely writing non-portable low-level code to begin with and would get little benefit from portable type declarations.)

What you *should* care about are things like the largest memory location you can address and whether it fits in an integer type, the size of the difference of two pointers or the size of the maximum array index, and so on. You might also care about width of types that interface to the system, such as the largest time period since epoch you can represent, or the largest index into the file you can address. You get all of these by tuning into the standard C types such as `intptr_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `size_t`, `time_t`, `off_t`, and others — this is what they're for.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped. I've learned that what I really want can be represented by the `(u)int_fast_##_t` and `(u)int_least_##_t` data types depending on what I want to optimize for.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

The closest is probably `int` which the standard says "...has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment..." That's somewhat vague and basically unenforceable though. Just for example, a number of 64-bit compilers still  use 32 bits for `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The signed equivalent of `std::size_t` is `std::ssize_t`.

Comment: It's really `std::size_t`. Simply `size_t` should not compile.

Comment: Sure. Unless there is a `using namespace std;` preceeding it.

Comment: `using namespace std;` cannot be recommended. I think there are plenty of posts on SO stating this.

Comment: Actually, it would be bad form to edit the post for such a correction on SO, unless it's a community wiki post. Suggesting the change in a comment is exactly the right venue.

Comment: `ssize_t` is not standard C++, it is based on a POSIX specification. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739797/711006

Answer (score 0):

If it exists in your version of `<cstdint>`, values of the form `uintN_t` (where `N` is the number of bits) and `intN_t` are exact width integer types.  They are optional, though.

Comment: I think the question was actually the opposite - is there a type that is 16 bit on a 16 bit platform, 32 bit on a 32 bit platform etc. The uintN_t types are always N-bit wide REGARDLESS of platform

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something using templates:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

template<int size> struct native_ints;

template<> struct native_ints<2> {
    using signed_int = std::int16_t;
    using unsigned_int = std::uint16_t;
};

template<> struct native_ints<4> {
    using signed_int = std::int32_t;
    using unsigned_int = std::uint32_t;
};

template<> struct native_ints<8> {
    using signed_int = std::int64_t;
    using unsigned_int = std::uint64_t;
};

using int_native_t = typename native_ints<sizeof(std::intptr_t)>::signed_int;
using uint_native_t = typename native_ints<sizeof(std::intptr_t)>::unsigned_int;
```

This relies on `intptr_t` having the size of the native machine integer.

Answer (score -1):

Accorting to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c) you can do

```
// Check windows
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
#if _WIN64
typedef uint64_t my_int;
#else
typedef uint32_t my_int;
#endif
#endif

// Check GCC
#if __GNUC__
#if __x86_64__ || __ppc64__
typedef uint64_t my_int;
#else
typedef uint32_t my_int;
#endif
#endif
```

But this is obviously not a solution for 16-bit architecture.