# What is the difference between ssize_t and std::size_t?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, size-t, ssize-t

What is the difference between these two? I'm led to believe that they are the same thing since when I declare

```
ssize_t size;
```

without `using namespace std` I get a compilation error. Changing the declaration to `std::size_t size;` fixes this.

Comment: One is signed, the other is not. Have you tried `std::ssize_t`?

Comment: Related: [should use size_t or ssize_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15739490/12149471)

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` the type of `sizeof`, which is large enough to express the size of any C++ object or array index. It's unsigned type.

`ssize_t` is signed type, which accounts for -1 as error return type. A good reference for `ssize_t` is:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/system_data_types.7.html

```
   ssize_t
          Include: <sys/types.h>.  Alternatively, <aio.h>,
          <monetary.h>, <mqueue.h>, <stdio.h>, <sys/msg.h>,
          <sys/socket.h>, <sys/uio.h>, or <unistd.h>.

          Used for a count of bytes or an error indication.
          According to POSIX, it shall be a signed integer type
          capable of storing values at least in the range [-1,
          SSIZE_MAX], and the implementation shall support one or
          more programming environments where the width of ssize_t
          is no greater than the width of the type long.
```